# Missing col-xs sizes using bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

In my react project, using react-bootstrap, it's loading all all the css for the grid sizes, except for the `xs` set.

the `xs` set does, however, get the default styles applied to all grid sizes, but does not include the media query.

Is there something obvious I am missing?

Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `-xs-` infix was removed from Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6, so the classes are simply, `col-1`, `col-2`.. `col-12`, etc...

Since Bootstrap is "mobile first", the `xs` breakpoint (<576px) is the default and are no media queries for it. There are only media queries for the larger breakpoints to override the smaller breakpoints. Starting with the smallest each breakpoint overrides the next..

`xs`(default) > overridden by `sm` >  overridden by `md` > overridden by `lg` > overridden by `xl`

Comment: Thank you! 

I was worried that this was the case. I am trying to force grids in the xs size, however they just are not compatible with this.